# semaphores not working correctly

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, threadpool, semaphore

i have been trying to write a program where i simulate Shortest First Job algorithms using threads and semaphores.Every thread is responsbile for printing its id when master thread tells him to do so.Master thread (main) will control when these jobs get printed on the screen. the following is what i have came up with but i seem to be doing something wrong that i couldnt figure out yet. I managed to get it print out jobs accordingly, but its always 2 of them that are missing out of 10.File format is "id(char) arrival(int) burst(int)".So i desperately need help here as i have been trying numerous things and alway end up in the same situation i had for hours.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

sem_t childs[MAX];
sem_t master;

int jobdone = 0;

typedef struct job
{
  int burst, arrival, wait_time, turn_around, executed, done;
  char id;
} JOB;

JOB jobs[MAX];

void ShortestFirstJob()
{

  int i, j;
  char id;
  int burst, arrival, wait_time, turn_around, done;
  for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < MAX - 1; j++)
    {
      if (jobs[j].arrival > jobs[j + 1].arrival)
      {
        id = jobs[j].id;
        done = jobs[j].done;
        burst = jobs[j].burst;
        arrival = jobs[j].arrival;
        wait_time = jobs[j].wait_time;
        turn_around = jobs[j].turn_around;
        jobs[j].id = jobs[j + 1].id;
        jobs[j].burst = jobs[j + 1].burst;
        jobs[j].wait_time = jobs[j + 1].wait_time;
        jobs[j].arrival = jobs[j + 1].arrival;
        jobs[j].turn_around = jobs[j + 1].turn_around;
        jobs[j].done = jobs[j + 1].done;
        jobs[j + 1].id = id;
        jobs[j + 1].burst = burst;
        jobs[j + 1].arrival = arrival;
        jobs[j + 1].wait_time = wait_time;
        jobs[j + 1].turn_around = turn_around;
        jobs[j + 1].done = done;

      }
    }
  }
  printf("SORT \n");
  for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
  {
    printf("%c %d %d\n", jobs[j].id, jobs[j].arrival, jobs[j].burst);
  }

}

void* PrintJob(void *params)
{

  char id = *((char*) params);

  int i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    if (id == jobs[i].id)
      break;
  }

  for (k = 0; k < jobs[i].burst; k++)
  {

    sem_wait(&childs[i]);
    printf("%c", id);
    fflush(stdout);
    jobs[i].executed += 1;

    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
      if ((i != j) && (jobs[j].arrival > 0))
      {
        jobs[j].arrival -= 1;
        jobs[j].wait_time += 1;
      }
    }

    sem_post(&master);
  }

  jobs[i].done = 1;
  jobdone++;

}
int main()
{

  pthread_t threadIds[MAX];
  char threadsIdx;
  int result;
  int i = 0;
  int j;
  int index[MAX];

  FILE* fp = fopen("joblist1.txt", "r");

  for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
  {
    sem_init(&childs[j], 0, 0);
  }
  sem_init(&master, 0, 1);

  char id;
  int arrival, burst;
  while (fscanf(fp, "%c %d %d\n", &id, &arrival, &burst) != EOF)
  {

    jobs[i].id = id;
    jobs[i].arrival = arrival;
    jobs[i].burst = burst;
    jobs[i].wait_time = 0;
    jobs[i].turn_around = 0;
    jobs[i].executed = 0;
    jobs[i].done = 0;

    i++;
  }

  for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
  {
    printf("%c %d %d\n", jobs[j].id, jobs[j].arrival, jobs[j].burst);
  }

  ShortestFirstJob();

  for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {

    if (pthread_create(&threadIds[i], NULL, PrintJob, &jobs[i].id) != 0)
    {
      perror("thread create");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  int k, c = 0;
  int min = 0;
  int in = 0;
  int value, flag = 0;
  while (jobdone < MAX)
  {

    k = 0;
    c = 0;

    sem_wait(&master);
    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
      if ((jobs[j].arrival == 0) && (jobs[j].done != 1))
      {
        index[k++] = j;
        c++;

      }
    }

    if (c == 1)
    {

      sem_post(&childs[index[0]]);

    }
    else if (c > 1)
    {

      min = jobs[index[0]].burst;
      for (j = 1; j < k; j++)
      {
        if (jobs[index[j]].burst <= min)
        {
          min = jobs[index[j]].burst;
          in = index[j];

        }
      }

      sem_post(&childs[in]);

    }

  }

  for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    pthread_join(threadIds[i], NULL );
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood very well some of your computations, but I found two problems.

First, in the function `PrintJob()`, you should set `jobs[i].done = 1;` before to post the master semaphore, because the main thread evaluate `jobs[i].done` to decide which thread it will wake up.

So the correct code for `PrintJob()` function should be:

```
void* PrintJob(void *params) {

  char id = *((char*) params);

  int i, j, k;
  for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    if (id == jobs[i].id) break;
  }

  for (k = 0; k < jobs[i].burst; k++) {
    sem_wait(&childs[i]);
    printf("%c", id);
    fflush(stdout);
    jobs[i].executed += 1;

    for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
    {
      if ((i != j) && (jobs[j].arrival > 0))
      {
        jobs[j].arrival -= 1;
        jobs[j].wait_time += 1;
      }
    }

    /////////////////////////////
    // Here:
    if(k == (jobs[i].burst - 1))
      jobs[i].done = 1;
      jobdone++;
    }
    /////////////////////////////

    sem_post(&master);
  }
}
```

The second problem is in the main thread. I don't know what is precisely the problem, but when I tested your program, the problem was here, the main thread tried to wake up a finished thread that had `jobs[index[j]].done` set to `1`. I'am not sure it is the main problem, but you seem to have forgotten to give a value to `in` when `jobs[index[0]].burst` is the minimum. So the correct code should be:

```
else if (c > 1) {

  min = jobs[index[0]].burst;

  // Here:
  in = index[0];

  for (j = 1; j < k; j++)
  {
    if (jobs[index[j]].burst <= min)
    {
      min = jobs[index[j]].burst;
      in = index[j];
    }
  }

  sem_post(&childs[in]);

}
```